# Cassandra in single node cluster crashes with "Unable to gossip with any peers"

Tags: cassandra

I have an instance of cassandra running on my server in single node configuration but a few minutes after startup it crashes with the following error:

```
ERROR [main] 2023-05-10 16:05:08,197 CassandraDaemon.java:911 - Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to gossip with any peers
    at org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper.doShadowRound(Gossiper.java:1844)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.checkForEndpointCollision(StorageService.java:650)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.prepareToJoin(StorageService.java:936)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:786)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:731)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:420)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:765)
```

Any idea on how to fix this? I find this especially weird given that all other threads I have found deal with multi-node configuration.

I have also checked the *commitlog* and the permissions there are fine.

seeds list:

```yaml
seed_provider:
    - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
      parameters:
          - seeds: "127.0.0.1:7000"
```

So, given that `127.0.0.1` is the `localhost` I would say the configuration is fine.

Comment: In your cassandra.yaml, do you have this node set in the seeds list?

Comment: I have updated the initial post with the required information.

Comment: So before it crashes, can you connect to it?  If so, run a `SELECT * FROM system.peers`.

Comment: A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra). For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it states in the error, the node cannot gossip with seeds.

You've configured `localhost` in the seeds list but Cassandra is not able to connect to `127.0.0.1` on gossip port `7000` which indicates that the node is not listening for gossip connections on `localhost`.

This would lead me to conclude that you've specified a different IP address for `listen_address`. You need to update the seeds list and set it to the same IP address.

For example:

```
listen_address: 10.1.2.3

seed_provider:
  - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
    parameters:
      - seeds: "10.1.2.3:7000"
```